# flutter issue in webview method flutter

Tags: flutter, webview

I try to use web view but I have error: The method 'WebView' isn't defined for the type '_MyWidgetState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'WebView'

[image: the problem]

I add webview_flutter: ^4.0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's now `WebView` it is `WebViewWidget`

You can use like below

```
return WebViewWidget(controller: controller);
```

Comment: how to add url?

Comment: You can checkout this. it have example as well https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter